# What short-term accommodation options are available in Singapore for a foreign middle-school student group?

Tags: accommodation, children, singapore

What are some suitable accommodation options for a group of twelve 10- to 13-year-old foreign children visiting Singapore for a week during a school trip? Ideally, it would be in or within reasonable commuting distance of the central area.

Hotels are an option, but would require arranging additional chaperones since each room would need an adult to supervise, and prices that I've seen are high. Airbnb has a few suitable listings for group stays, but I understand that it is not legal for short-term stays. What other options should I look into?

Comment: Have you considered contacting schools/school districts in Singapore?  They might love to host a group.

Comment: Airbnb is illegal for private homes.

Comment: I love these cultural differences where in some cultures that age group is considered old enough for (international) travel by themselves, whilst in other cultures it's too young to be alone in a room  . Anyway, probably not relevant depending on the goal, but Johor has some fantastic accomodation options for **far** more reasonable prices, but depends on what you consider a 'reasonable commute' (it's *long*, but doable). Also maybe worth trying is booking out an entire small hostel. In general (not specifically Singapore) there are many hostels with 3 or 4 rooms with 4-8 beds each.

Comment: +100 for your first sentence, @DavidMulder!

Comment: If its a school Trip  shouldn't your school be organizing it ?

Comment: @dezkev Indeed, I am a staff member at my school, and one of those responsible for doing preliminary research for and organizing the trip.

Comment: @PeterM Thank you for the good suggestion. I should have mentioned that this trip would be a summer program trip (in June), so outside the school year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Singapore is small enough that there's little domestic demand for student trip accommodation, but you do have some options.  In no particular order:

- [Salvation Army Praisehaven Retreat](https://www.salvationarmy.org.sg/wwd-praisehaven-retreat-centre/), Hillview
- [Sarimbun Scout Camp](https://www.sldc.edu.sg/venue-rental), Sungei Buloh. Location is quite far as far as Singapore goes, but still only ~30 min from the city.  Was rather run down when my kids stayed here towards the end of COVID, hopefully they've cleaned up.  12 students only may be a little too small a group though.
- [YMCA Orchard](https://www.ymca.org.sg/hospitality/ymcaoneorchard/) is more like a hotel, but still good value given its *very* central location right on Orchard Rd in the heart of the city.
- There are also a large number of fairly basic [chalets](https://www.sassymamasg.com/chalets-singapore-family/) around Singapore, but these are often tough to book because they have membership requirements and/or book out well in advance.

Comment: My experience in Singapore tells me everything in Orchard is expensive, and *incredibly busy*, but it kind of depends on which part of Central Singapore they want to go to

Comment: @DialFrost Most of our activity would be in the Newton area.

Comment: @Chalcosoma YMCA Orchard would work well then, it's a few MRT stops away from Newton.

Answer (score 3):

> within reasonable commuting distance of the central area.

That's the whole of Singapore. And the subway (MRT) network is quite convenient. So that part is easy.

As you have discovered, short-term renting is frowned upon in Singapore. There is a number of student dormitories, but they house usually long-term students, so a week-long rental is going to be difficult. Although during school holidays in Singapore there may be vacancies, with foreign students going back home.

Having chaperones in hotel rooms with children could be complicated, as that might conflict with local laws. You know, unrelated adults and minors sleeping together... We have Singaporeans on this forum, they may know for sure.

Contacting schools as suggested in the comments is probably a great idea, and could lead to solutions like homestays. No idea how feasible that is in Singapore, but worth a shot.

Comment: Chaperones should be ok. They may give a separate bed.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. To clarify, my understanding is that hotels in most countries can't legally allow minors to stay alone in a room without adult supervision, so I would need chaperones to comply with the law (the students are mature enough that, if the law doesn't require it, they wouldn't need constant adult supervision). I assumed but didn't check yet if Singapore has this requirement; I suppose this is a question for hotels.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at a serviced apartment. I had my friends stayed in one of those and it was ok. Not sure of the popular companies. You can google it.

It is legal in Singapore and its easy to chaperone the children.

Answer (score 3):

I have lived in Singapore for many years, and I think contacting schools wouldn't hurt. Try to have 12 kids in a hotel could be tricky to find and handle. Some schools have dormitories too, so that could be an option as well.

Now I'm not exactly crystal clear how this would work out, but just a note of caution, there aren't too many dormitories or boarding schools in Singapore.

You could look at [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294265-i1748-k10234181-Dormitory_accommodation_for_visiting_school_group-Singapore.html) for more options. This link only provides answers for 2 nights unfortunately, so staying for 1 week might not suit your needs.